# Intellij ultimate keyboard shortcuts not working on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave, intellij-13

I have recently updated my MacOS to Mojave (version 10.14.6 to be specific).

And i have Intellij version 2018.3.6 (Ultimate edition).

After updating the OS all the keyboard shortcuts which used to work well are not working fine.

For example, Command + '{' moves the cursor to the end of the file now, but it should have moved to the selected code or function (as was earlier done).

I checked the intellij community on following links:

[link1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000537010-Keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-IntelliJUltimate)

[link2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206558579-Keymaps-and-useful-shortcuts-what-to-do-if-a-shortcut-is-not-working-)

But no luck.

Any suggestion on how to revert back all shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issues using following steps:

1. Go to Intellij preferences.
2. Click Keymap in left panel.
3. In the right panel, change the drop down value in keymap to "Mac OS X 10.5+".
   [image]